# Parsing string into Float - Android

Tags: java, android

Hoping someone can help.

I am getting weather for a certain location using the Google Weather API.
When the temperature is returned, it is returned in Kevin format which I am wanting convert to Celsius.

Unfortunately my code throws the error; Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "temperature"

I need to be able to parse the String into a Float or Double so i can convert it to Celsius. I can't obviously convert a string to Celsius as its text and not a number.

Which is happening when I am trying to convert from Kevin to Celsius. Can someone help find what i am doing wrong?

```
public void open(View view){
    String url = location.getText().toString();
    String finalUrl = url1 + url;
    country.setText(finalUrl);
    obj = new HandleJSON(finalUrl);
    obj.fetchJSON();

    float celsius = 273.15f;

    String temp = obj.getTemperature().toString();
    Float finalTemp = Float.parseFloat(temp) - celsius;

    while(obj.parsingComplete);
    country.setText(obj.getCountry());
    temperature.setText(finalTemp.toString());
    humidity.setText(obj.getHumidity());
    pressure.setText(obj.getPressure());
}
```

Error Log***

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "temperature"
at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:114)
at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:323)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:306)
at com.testing.listco.testrecycler.MainActivity.open(MainActivity.java:47)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

HandleJSON**

```
public class HandleJSON {
private String country = "country";
private String temperature = "temperature";
private String humidity = "humidity";
private String pressure = "pressure";
private String urlString = null;

public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;

public HandleJSON(String url){
    this.urlString = url;
}

public String getCountry(){
    return country;
}
public String getTemperature(){
    return temperature;
};
public String getHumidity(){
    return humidity;
}
public String getPressure(){
    return pressure;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void readAndrParseJSON(String in){
    try {
        JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(in);

        JSONObject sys = reader.getJSONObject("sys");
        country = sys.getString("country");

        JSONObject main = reader.getJSONObject("main");

        temperature = main.getString("temp");
        pressure = main.getString("pressure");
        humidity = main.getString("humidity");

        parsingComplete = false;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        //TODO: Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public void fetchJSON(){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    //Starts the query
                    InputStream stream =  conn.getInputStream();

                    String data = convertStreatToString(stream);

                    readAndrParseJSON(data);
                    readAndrParseJSON(data);
                    stream.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }

    static String convertStreatToString(java.io.InputStream is){
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }

}
```

Comment: String temp = obj.getTemperature().toString(); isn't doing what you expect as it ends up `temp = "temperature"` which isn't a valid float to parse. It seems getTemperature() is returning "temperature" instead of the actual temperature.

Comment: Sorry, i should have explained more, I know where the error is happening. What i need to do is parse the temperature into a float or double so i can convert it to Celcius.

Comment: And @zgc7009 told you exactly why it's failing.

Comment: You aren't actually getting the temperature, you are getting the String "temperature". Try making sure getTemperature() returns a String representation of a float, something like "10.50".

Comment: Do you have the source code for `HandleJSON`?

Comment: Thanks, So i tried this way, but still getting the same error. Im new to java also... Float finalTemp = Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(obj.getTemperature()));

Comment: What the hell is `while(obj.parsingComplete);`?? Is this on the main thread? Do you expect some other thread to change that state? Do you realize the danger of your code just hanging, right there?

Comment: David, Sizik, i have updated the code to show HandleJSON. Hopefully this makes more sense now?

Comment: You don't check if parsing is complete before using the temperature, and since it isn't (clearly), the temperature still has its initial default value of "temperature".

Comment: @DavidConrad i can get the value to display if Temperature stays as a String.

Comment: All, i have fixed my issue. I was trying to convert the temperature to a float before i returned temperature from the API. I appreciate all of you putting up with my incompetence in not seeing this first. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the culprit:

```
String temp = obj.getTemperature().toString();
```

This assigns the string "temperature" to the string `temp`, and you are trying to convert the float "temperature" to an integer. This is not possible, because the string "temperature" is - obviously - not a float.

Comment: Sorry, i should have explained more, I know where the error is happening. What i need to do is parse the temperature into a float or double so i can convert it to Celsius.

Comment: @Matt First you have to *get* the temperature. Only then can you hope to parse it into a float or a double, or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "temperature"

"temperature" is not a valid float therefore that exception is thrown. A valid float would be 4.5, etc.

Comment: Sorry, i should have explained more, I know where the error is happening. What i need to do is parse the temperature into a float or double so i can convert it to Celsius.